How to adjust flutter camera aspect ratio being compressed for Facial recognition
I've created an app in flutter that can do facial recognition on someone using tensorflow.
The app opens up the camera and checks for faces that are stored in the database or checks for faces and allows the user to add the face to the database, hence remembering it for next time.
The facial detection works fine but the issue I'm having is with the camera and its aspect ratio. The camera seems unreasonably stretched out and it causes the box to be drawn to the left of the face on a real android camera.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(_detectedFaces.isNotEmpty ? _detectedFaces[0] : 'No faces detected');
    if (_detectedFaces.isNotEmpty) {
      // Show text Marked
    }
    List<Widget> stackChildren = [];
    final size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
    if (_controller != null) {
      stackChildren.add(Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          left: 0.0,
          width: size.width,
          height: size.height,
          child: CameraPreview(_controller)));

      stackChildren.add(
        Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
            child: buildResult()),
      );
    }


and how did that happen, the camera image being stretched? is that not just a GUI/displaying issue, i.e. not affecting the image data?

@ChristophRackwitz it doesnt affect the image data but I believe it affects performance. I think it is a displaying issue, something to do with changing the aspect ratio of the camerapreview comparative to the screen

you can use aspectRatio to keep the ratio of the camera,
and then use FittedBox and specify the width and height.
Here's an example with your code using the FittedBox with aspectRatio:
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  print(_detectedFaces.isNotEmpty ? _detectedFaces[0] : 'No faces detected');
  if (_detectedFaces.isNotEmpty) {
    // Show text Marked
  }

  List<Widget> stackChildren = [];
  final size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);

  if (_controller != null) {
    // Ensure the camera preview maintains its aspect ratio
    final aspectRatio = _controller.value.aspectRatio;

    stackChildren.add(Positioned(
      top: 0.0,
      left: 0.0,
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      child: ClipRect(
        child: OverflowBox(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: size.width,
              height: size.width / aspectRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(_controller),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));

    stackChildren.add(
      Positioned(
        top: 0.0,
        left: 0.0,
        width: size.width,
        height: size.height,
        child: buildResult(),
      ),
    );
  }

  return Stack(children: stackChildren);
}


